# Hide data on click or on load depending on class

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have `div` tags on my page. Which is toggled like tabs.

```
<div class="cntstdtl_01 {{ !strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'page') ? 'active' : '' }}">
//data here if url don't contain word page
</div>

<div class="cntstdtl_02 {{ strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'page') ? 'active' : '' }}">
//display if URL has page word 
</div>

//show if cntstdtl_02 has an active class, hide otherwise
<div class="page">
//show data
</div>
```

I tried doing like this:

```
$('.page').hide();
$('#cntstdtl_01').on('click', function(){
$('.page').hide();
  });
$('#cntstdtl_02').on('click', function(){
  $('.page').show();
 });
```

I tried also doing this

```
  $('#cntstdtl_01').on('click', function(){
    if($('div.cntstdtl_01').hasClass('active')){

    $('.page').hide();
   }
 });//this isn't working
```

But my problem with this one is that if I have to click the toggle first before it takes effect. What I want is to automatically show the div if `cntstdtl_02` has active class wither on page load or click.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you just need some CSS

Comment: @PatrickQ Which part?

Comment: Use the same logic for `.page` as you have for `.cntstdtl_02` to determine if it should be shown on page load. Then go with the JS you have for toggle it's display on click.

Comment: How about if on page load scenario? it works on  click but not on page load,

Comment: All you need to know, do is in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for the inputs, and I have done it this way:

```
if($('#cntstdtl_01').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.page').hide();
}

$('#cntstdtl_01').on('click', function(){
    $('.page').hide();
 });
$('#cntstdtl_02').on('click', function(){
    $('.page').show();
});
```

Comment: Dumb question, but if you're always targeting the same element $('.page') and always want to make sure it has the class active, why not just do $('.active').on('click'. function(){ $('.page').show(); });

Comment: Best to use CSS as much as you can and javascript only when you need it.

Comment: I agree with @dmikester1, there's no need to use JS to hide the `.page` element by default. Use CSS to hide it initially. Whether you do that by adding a class to `.page` (via PHP) or setting `.page` to `display: none;` by default is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

In your css file you can create a helper class `.hide{ display: none }` and add this class to your `<div class="page hide"></div>` and with jquery check if `cntstdtl_02` has the active class then remove the `hide` class.

```
if ($('.cntstdtl_02').hasClass('active')) {
   $('.page').removeClass('hide')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately, this does not make any changes. :(

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that your HTML is actually in the exact order shown in your question.  It is a CSS-only solution, which I believe is preferred to a Javascript/jQuery solution when possible.

```
div.page {
  display: none;
}

div.cntstdtl_02.active + div.page {
  display: block;
}
```

You are defaulting the "page" div to not show.  Then if there is a div with classes "cntstdtl_02" and "active", whose next element is the "page" div, we show the "page" div.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gpjkzdvc/). Currently shows the "page" div, because the "active" class is present.  Remove the "active" class, run the fiddle, and you will see the "page" div disappear.

```css
div.page {
  display: none;
}

div.cntstdtl_02.active + div.page {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="cntstdtl_01 active">
data here if url don't contain word page
</div>

<div class="cntstdtl_02 active">
display if URL has page word 
</div>

<!-- show if cntstdtl_02 has an active class, hide otherwise -->
<div class="page">
show data
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding document ready function.
no need to click, document ready runs after page loads.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if ($('.cntstdtl_02').hasClass('active')) {
       $('.page').removeClass('hide')
    }
});
```